# Issue of calling a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, compiler-errors

I have create a stored procedure and I call it from Visual Studio, but when I call stored procedure, the program has an compiler error. The stored procedure does exist in SQL Server.

This is error :

> no overload "sumtotal" for method takes 0 argument

Stored procedure in SQL Server :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sumtotal(@totaling int output)
AS
BEGIN
declare @sum int
set @sum=(select SUM(amount_income) from IncomeTable)
insert into Total_Table(Total_Income)
values(@sum)
    set @totaling=@sum
    return @totaling
END
GO
```

in VS:

```
AccountDBClassDataContext context = new AccountDBClassDataContext();
int total;

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dataIncome = context.sumtotal();
}
```

I know maybe my question was stupid question but this is a question.

Please help me .

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one `output` parameter specified in stored procedure, so you have to pass it when you're calling it:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int? dataIncome = null;
   context.sumtotal(ref dataIncome);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I write "context.sumtotal(out dataIncome);" but when i run, the program has error. The best overloaded method match for 'Accountant_App.AccountDBClassDataContext.sumtotal(ref int?)' has some invalid arguments , and , Argument 1: cannot convert from 'out int' to 'ref int?' . why? what should i do?

Comment: Thanks. but why should i use of int? ? and what is difference between int? and int? When i create a str prc and when i call this , should i use 'ref' variable with 'int?' type?  I write this but the program has error: Use of unassigned local variable 'dataa'

Comment: `int?` is really transformed into `Nullable<int>` and you have to use that, because your SP can not return any value. The difference is, `int?` can be set to `null` while standard `int` can't.

Comment: Thanks but again my program has error.The error is:  Use of unassigned local variable 'dataa' . Why? How can i solve this? I set int type in SP, you mean, when i create SP with output variable, i should use int?for give value of param?